# iReport Designer: permission denied for relation

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, jasper-reports, ireport

I didn't face this error before. I have a database `db`, that contains a table `tb_name`, I create a connection in iReport Designer with credentials of the `db` owner. Then I create new report, but the query `select * from tb_name;` throws the following error:

> SQL problems: ERROR: permission denied for relation tb_name
>   Query error
>
> Message:
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: SQL problems: ERROR: permission denied for relation tb_name Level:
>       SEVERE Stack Trace: SQL problems: ERROR: permission denied for relation tb_name
>       com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.data.fieldsproviders.SQLFieldsProvider.getFields(SQLFieldsProvider.java:435)
>       com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.readFields(JDBCConnection.java:470)
>       com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.wizards.ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.validate(ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.java:146)
>       org.openide.WizardDescriptor$7.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1357)
>       org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
>       org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)

When I test connection everything's fine. What can be a reason of this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if the user has rights to execute statements. Some database changes might have caused the user to lose query permission.

Comment: @user845279 Oh, thanks a lot, it helped. You should probably post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the user has rights to execute statements. Some database changes might have caused the user to lose query permission.